# Impact of circular dependence between libraries in applications

Tags: c++, linux, windows

I've always wondered about this. Suppose I have a program (or application) A most of whose libraries link to pre-compiled libraries in application B; is it OK then to make parts of application B link to specific libraries in application A?

Comment: No, it's not. It makes the build process much, much more complicated if not impossible.

Comment: Circular dep in build sucks bigtime, don't go there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the relationship of A and B, and the relationship of A's libraries, L(A), to A, and the relationship of B's libraries, L(B), to B.

If L(B) is in any way dependent on B, since A is dependent on L(B), then A is dependent on B, and I would go so far as to say that A and B are essentially one application. In this situation, it won't make much difference if B links with L(A), except that the eventual separation of concerns will be more difficult in the long run.

To accomplish this, however, you will have to ensure that the subset of L(B) that A or L(A) links to is not dependent on L(A).

If L(B) is independent of B (*it can be considered a set of reusable libraries*), then I would say that L(B) isn't really a part of B beyond the fact that B links to it. So there is a clear separation of concern between A and B at linktime and it's inadvisable to link B to L(A), unless of course if L(A) is independent of A and can also be considered a set of isolated, reusable libraries.

Comment: I like the more nuanced approach you're trying to take, but I'm not sure you've yet characterized it correctly. Let's suppose B has multiple libraries, L1(B), L2(B), L3(B); collectively L*(B). If A depends on libraries L*(B), then to build A, you must have completed the build of L*(B). If, however, any of L*(B) depends on something from A, then you have build A before you can build B, which leaves you in a chicken-and-egg quandary. Separating the components to avoid the circularity of reference is crucial. Maybe L3(B) depends on L2(A), but most of A depends on L1(B) and L2(B). _[continued]_

Comment: _[continued]_ In that case, you would build (B - L3(B)), A, then L3(B).  That's a bit crude; there are presumably some programs in B that depend on L3(B), so they'd be built in the third phase.  But the crucial point is that you have to break the circular dependency somehow, and partitioning the builds is the appropriate, arguably necessary, step.

Comment: You're correct. You might have formulated your comment while I was editing. I added a statement about that .... or was I unclear in how I phrased it?  I like your description better, anyways.

Comment: I suppose my concern is that your L(A) and L(B) don't show the fact that there will be separate libraries in L(A) and L(B); multiple libraries.  If there are single libraries L1(A) and L2(B) where L1(A) depends on stuff in L2(B) and stuff in L2(B) depends on stuff in L1(A), then life is hell! I've worked with a pair of libraries with incestuous cross-references; one refactoring removed an unused function in one library and broke the (static) linking of a load of code because the removed function x-ref'd stuff in the other library. The link already rescanned the libraries; adding a 3rd scan...

Comment: I ended up reinserting an incestuous cross-reference to keep the links working, but the correct solution would have been to combine the two libraries into a single one.  There were some reasons not to do it (inertia was one such; cross-platform build issues were another), but that was the correct solution.  Circular dependencies should be avoided whenever possible!